# Regex to remove CDATA wrapper from an XHTML file

Tags: javascript, regex, cdata

I'm trying to remove the CDATA wrapper in the following script (content has to be wrapped by CDATA to pass XHTML validation):

```
<script id="tplTest" type="text/html">

//<![CDATA[ 
<p id="msg">Hello</p>
<p>Another test: <#= ddd.ArtID #></p> 
//]]>

</script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var strTmp = document.getElementById("tplTest").innerHTML;
var strNew = strTmp.replace(/[\/(\/!\[)\]CDATA]/g, "").replace(/[(\/\/\]\])]/g, "");
```

It removes most to the CDATA mark-up except for the start/end (`<`, `>`) tags:

```
< 
<p id="msg">Hello<p>
<p>nother test: <#= ddd.rtI #><p> 
>
```

Question: How should I modify the regex to additionally remove these leading and trailing `<`, `>` tags?

Answer (score 5):

You could just replace the raw string and skip using regular expressions all-together:

```
"FOO BAR".replace("FOO", ""); // replace "FOO" with "" (nothing)
```

In your case:

```
var stringToSanitize = "//<![CDATA[ xxx //]]>";

var sanitizedString = stringToSanitize
                      .replace("//<![CDATA[", "")
                      .replace("//]]>", "");
```

Regular expressions in JavaScript are slow. So on top of you getting your problem solved, you might see a slight speed-increase using my example.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it enough to just add a `<` after the first slash in the first `replace` and a '>' after the last slash in the last `replace`? If your regex dialect takes these angle brackets as magic characters (few do) you can use `\<` and `\>` respectively, i.e., escape them with backslashes.